# How to select multiple image from slider layout?

Tags: android

i have a slider layout with four images. I want to use multi select function in it, whenever user touches or clicks on any image , then that image will be selected for next operation.

For example multi select in gallery or filtration in some applications.

```
/* Insert data in Slider of Brands */
        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        HashMap<String, Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        file_maps.put("Life is a Journey. Enjoy the Ride.", R.drawable.nissan);
        file_maps.put("Drive your way.", R.drawable.image1);
        file_maps.put("Moving forward.", R.drawable.image2);
        file_maps.put("It must be .", R.drawable.image3);
        file_maps.put("It must be love.", R.drawable.image4);
        for (String name : file_maps.keySet()) {
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
```

//function for clicking event

```
  public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

        }
```

Comment: did you code something?

Comment: check my update

Comment: is this a custom or 3rd party library?

Comment: 3rd party library

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132264/discussion-between-anoop-mishra-and-xfighter).